# How to a convert a Dictionary Slice to a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, slice

I'm trying to convert `myDictionary.dropFirst()` to a new dictionary missing one key (I don't care which one). `dropFirst()` returns a Slice. I want a new Dictionary of the same type as `myDictionary`.

You can convert an Array slice to an array like this `let array = Array(slice)`. What's the equivalent for a Dictionary? If I try Dictionary(slice) I get the compilation error `Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `DictionarySlice` like there is `ArraySlice`. Instead, `dropFirst()` returns a `Slice<Dictionary>` which doesn't support key subscripting like `Dictionary` does. However, you can loop through a `Slice<Dictionary>` with key-value pairs just like you can with `Dictionary`:

```
let dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3]

var smallerDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]

for (key, value) in dictionary.dropFirst() {
    smallerDictionary[key] = value
}

print(smallerDictionary) // ["a": 1, "c": 3]
```

An extension would make this a bit more elegant:

```
extension Dictionary {

    init(_ slice: Slice<Dictionary>) {
        self = [:]

        for (key, value) in slice {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }

}

let dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3]
let smallerDictionary = Dictionary(dictionary.dropFirst())
print(smallerDictionary) // ["a": 1, "c": 3]
```

I wouldn't really recommend doing this, though, because

- you don't know which key-value pair will be dropped, and
- it's not truly random either.

But if you really want to do this, now you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: [1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3].dropFirst())
```

See my `Note` for why this overload is necessary to make that compile.

```swift
extension Dictionary {
  /// Creates a new dictionary from the key-value pairs in the given sequence.
  ///
  /// - Parameter keysAndValues: A sequence of key-value pairs to use for
  ///   the new dictionary. Every key in `keysAndValues` must be unique.
  /// - Returns: A new dictionary initialized with the elements of `keysAndValues`.
  /// - Precondition: The sequence must not have duplicate keys.
  /// - Note: Differs from the initializer in the standard library, which doesn't allow labeled tuple elements.
  ///     This can't support *all* labels, but it does support `(key:value:)` specifically,
  ///     which `Dictionary` and `KeyValuePairs` use for their elements.
  init<Elements: Sequence>(uniqueKeysWithValues keysAndValues: Elements)
  where Elements.Element == Element {
    self.init(
      uniqueKeysWithValues: keysAndValues.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }
    )
  }
}
```