# How to easlily convert a Dictionary<K,V>.Subsequence to Dictionary<K,V>

Tags: swift

[UPDATED] Digging the Dictionary methods I found:

```
.split(whereSeparator: (key, value)) -> [Slice.Dictionary<K,V>]
```

returning a subsequences made of:

```
_startIndex, _endIndex and _base (that contains the original Dict)
```

I tried it for fun. Using the result to get a Dict needs a loop to create a dict from indexes.

Do you know a way to easily convert Subsequence to Dict has we do it with subsequence String?:

```
String(subsequence)
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered so how would the split happen exactly at a given entry? It could be different on each execution.

Comment: Splitting a dictionary *really* doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: @Alexander > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629496/how-to-split-an-hashmap-in-java

Comment: Probably better to use filter in my opinion

Comment: Would be easier to use a `reduced(into:_:)` instead of strange splits, etc.

Answer (score 1):

While your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120640/how-to-a-convert-a-dictionary-slice-to-a-dictionary-in-swift), it's not quite enough for `split`, which also requires flat-mapping or an equivalent, due to it involving multiple slices.

```swift
Dictionary(
  uniqueKeysWithValues:
    [1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3]
    .split { $0.key > 2 } // filters out (key: 3, value: 3)
    .flatMap { $0 }
)
```

However, I don't think it's actually useful, because using `filter`, with an inverted condition, yields the same result.

```swift
[1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3].filter { $0.key <= 2 }
```

If, instead, you want both split portions, as dictionaries, you can use this, which relies on the same `uniqueKeysWithValues` extension initializer.

```swift
// [false: [2: 2, 1: 1], true: [3: 3]]
Dictionary(grouping: [1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3]) { $0.key > 2 }
  .mapValues(Dictionary.init)
```

```swift
extension Dictionary {
  /// Creates a new dictionary from the key-value pairs in the given sequence.
  ///
  /// - Parameter keysAndValues: A sequence of key-value pairs to use for
  ///   the new dictionary. Every key in `keysAndValues` must be unique.
  /// - Returns: A new dictionary initialized with the elements of `keysAndValues`.
  /// - Precondition: The sequence must not have duplicate keys.
  /// - Note: Differs from the initializer in the standard library, which doesn't allow labeled tuple elements.
  ///     This can't support *all* labels, but it does support `(key:value:)` specifically,
  ///     which `Dictionary` and `KeyValuePairs` use for their elements.
  init<Elements: Sequence>(uniqueKeysWithValues keysAndValues: Elements)
  where Elements.Element == Element {
    self.init(
      uniqueKeysWithValues: keysAndValues.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jessy. So first the .flatMap { $0 } then an extension of Dictionary to support init with labeled tuples.